# How to find the hardware model tested by the apple team in iOS crash reports

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I recently had an app rejected from the Apple due to `crash`, but I'm unable to reproduce the crash from our end. I have checked the all compatible devices: `iPhone`, `iPad` and `iPod`. However, I'm still unable to reproduce the crash.

**My question is:** How do I learn which device was used by the Apple team to test the app. In crash reports they mentioned `Hardware Model: xxx`. Please, does anyone know how to find the `Hardware Model` used by the Apple team?

> Incident Identifier: 71C3E97D-4DF2-A84F-5EB28058AA11 CrashReporter
>   Key:   025fa689e0eb7fe33eaf5858d306609d6fb Hardware Model:      xxx
>   Process:             ------- [225] Path:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/1EE9FA90-432C-B19E-92ACE9AD72C5/------.app/------
>   Identifier:          ------------ Version:             1.0 (1.0) Code
>   Type:           ARM-64 (Native) Parent Process:      launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:           2014-12-02 10:32:31.758 -0800 Launch Time:
>   2014-12-02 10:18:02.789 -0800 OS Version:          iOS 8.1.1 (12B435)
>   Report Version:      105
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Last Exception Backtrace: (0x18510e59c 0x195c840e4 0x184ff91f8
>   0x100086e1c 0x1000ddca0 0x1898c0aa0 0x1898c07b0 0x18993d060
>   0x18993cf74 0x1899afa48 0x189bd7f18 0x189bd86c0 0x1899adcf0
>   0x1899e3058 0x1899e2024 0x1899b3e90 0x1899b27cc 0x1899b051c
>   0x189bda218 0x1899e78c4 0x18998fec4 0x18998fec4 0x18998fc60
>   0x1000a48c0 0x18fc4a148 0x18b4e4438 0x18b540c1c 0x18b536acc
>   0x18b54053c 0x183992bc0 0x1839c6660 0x1839c66b8 0x1962c93ac
>   0x1962c936c 0x1962cd980 0x1850c5fa4 0x1850c404c 0x184ff10a4
>   0x18e1675a4 0x1899263c0 0x1001337e0 0x1962f2a08)

Comment: Have you tested on physical devices, or just with the iOS Simulator? The notes from Apple should include the specific model as well as a rough description of what they did to get the app to crash. The 'xxx' is a placeholder present in all their crash reports.

Comment: Yes,I tested on both simulator and physical devices,but I'm unable to reproduce the crash from our end. My question is - Is it possible to get the information on which devices the apple team tested the app? If the device specified , I will test on the specified device.Thank you

Comment: See this class for `hw.model`: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-Hardware.m which would probably give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but maybe useful to others. The only way I found so far to get the **hardware model identifier** of an iOS device was by taking the approach seen in [this](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-Hardware.m) class. Please comment if there is another way.

For the sake of possible loss of this link, here a summary of how to do it with minor changes (Objective C):

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

...

- (NSString*)hardwareModelIdentifier
{
  char* typeSpecifier = "hw.model";
  size_t size;
  sysctlbyname(typeSpecifier, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

  char* answer = malloc(size);
  sysctlbyname(typeSpecifier, answer, &size, NULL, 0);
  
  NSString* modelIdentifier = [NSString stringWithCString:answer encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  free(answer);
  return modelIdentifier;
}
```

The result should match the "internal name" column on this [list](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models). E.g. for an iPhone 12 you should get D53gAP.

Note that this is **not** App Store proven. Let me know if you successfully submitted an app using this approach.

Further note that in the header `sysctl.h` next to `model` it says `/* Deprecated: use hw.target */`.

My tests with Xcode 12.0.1 and iOS 13.7 did reveal that at the point of writing this, only using the chars `hw.model` provided a result where as `hw.target` didn't provide any result (tested on simulator and device).